# How can I get the messages that was sent by agent using Live Agent API?

Tags: liveagent, chat

I am getting error 503 for Live Agent APIs. How can I get the messages that was sent by agent using Live Agent API?

```
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Map<String,String> mapHeader = new Map<String,String>();
mapHeader.put('X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION','36');
mapHeader.put('X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY', '**********');
mapHeader.put('X-LIVEAGENT-SESSION-KEY', '***********');
mapHeader.put('X-LIVEAGENT-SEQUENCE', '1');


JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField('organizationId', '*********');
    gen.writeStringField('deploymentId', '*************');
    gen.writeStringField('buttonId', '**********');
    gen.writeStringField('sessionId', '18c52-');
    gen.writeStringField('userAgent', '');
    gen.writeStringField('language', 'en-US');
    gen.writeStringField('screenResolution', '1366x768');
    gen.writeStringField('visitorName', 'Arun');
    gen.writeFieldName('prechatDetails');
        gen.writeStartArray();
        gen.writeEndArray();
    gen.writeFieldName('prechatEntities');
        gen.writeStartArray();
        gen.writeEndArray();
    gen.writeBooleanField('receiveQueueUpdates', true);
    gen.writeBooleanField('isPost', true);
    gen.writeEndObject();

 String body = gen.getAsString();
res = WebServiceCalloutwithbody.invoke('https://d.la10.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/Chasitor/ChasitorInit',mapHeader,'POST',body);
```

Comment: Titles should be a concise description of the problem. Your post should contain words that describe at a high level what you are trying to achieve and pinpointing the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. your end point `/chat/rest/Chasitor/ChasitorInit` is used to send the request to live agent console for chat this endpoint only results in status code 200 for success
2. end point that you need to hit is `/chat/rest/System/Messages` that returns live agent message

   ```
   Http http=new Http();

   HttpRequest request=new HttpRequest();

   request.setMethod('GET');

   request.setEndpoint(host+'/chat/rest/System/Messages);

   request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');

   request.setHeader('X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION',String.valueOf(API_VERSION));

   request.setHeader('X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY',AFFINITY);

   request.setHeader('X-LIVEAGENT-SESSION-KEY',SESSION_KEY);

   HttpResponse response=http.send(request);
   ```

> You have to append ack parameter to end point [check this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_Messages.htm)

this will give u json of all the messages

the [response](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_response_bodies.htm#Messages) you get from this contains live agents message or other activity

Comment: i get `Request is not a valid Messages` with 400 status. I am sending `ack=-1` in query params